# PHP OOP - newbi - how do I get strlen of property and not object

Tags: php, regex, oop, authentication, strlen

I am not grasping OOP properties/methods/objects/etc...

how do I get strlen of property and not object in a class.
I am obviously doing it wrong, do I need another method for the strlen?

login.php

```
$act = isset( $_POST['act'] ) ? $_POST['act'] : '' ;

switch ($act) {
case 'login':

$username = new CleanData($_POST['username']);
$username-> set_minlength('8');
$username-> set_maxlength('250');
$username-> set_pregtype('replace');
$username-> set_regex('/[^ \p{L}\d-\_\@+\.]+/u');
$uname = $username->cleaner();

etc...
```

class

```
class CleanData{
protected $data;
protected $minlength;
protected $maxlength;
protected $pregtype;
protected $regex;
protected $replaced;

function __construct($data){
    $this->data = trim($data);
    $this->data = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/u', ' ', $this->data);
}

function set_minlength($minlength){
    $this->minlength = $minlength;
}

function set_maxlength($maxlength){
    $this->maxlength = $maxlength;
}

function set_pregtype($pregtype){
    $this->pregtype = $pregtype;
}

function set_regex($regex){
    $this->regex = $regex;
}

public function cleaner(){

    $response = '';

    if ($this->pregtype == 'match') {
        if(preg_match($this->regex, $this->data)){
            $response = $this->data;
    }
    }elseif ($this->pregtype == 'replace') {
        $this->replaced = preg_replace($this->regex, '', $this->data);
        if(strlen($this->replaced) >= $this->minlength && strlen($this->replaced) <= $this->maxlength) {
            $response = $this->replaced;
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
}
```

Notice: Object of class CleanData could not be converted to int

Comment: Why do you have `<= $this` when it's clear you need `<= $this->maxlength`?

Comment: I am a little lost. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy - not sure what happened there, fixed it though.

Comment: Also, you need to learn the differences between == and === operators, and how to properly compare strings!

Comment: @Gacci  -  need to make sure string length is valid. I am probably going at it wrong though.

Comment: @Gacci - This is my second day writing php after almost 10 years off, I am a little rusty to say the least.

Comment: Please explain what I am doing wrong... http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: What exactly you don't get!

Comment: Your code may work sometimes and may not some others. === or !== compare the type meaning that it makes sure that you are not only comparing the content but the type as well. For instance comparing 0 == '0' will give you true bug 0 === '0' will give you false. The first just compares the content '0' is type casted to 0. There fore it yields true. The second is als comparing the types (which are not equal) one is an integer the other is a string